# How to determine if a figure is contained within another figure in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have 2 figures. Both are irregular figures that are plotted using information about their vertices. How can I determine if no point of figure 1 lies outside figure 2?

Comment: By 'figure' do you mean polygon?

Comment: @Staus
Yes. Taking hint from your comment, I searched and was used inpolygon function